# how to save files to Context.MODE_PRIVATE using android DownloadManager

Tags: android

I am using `DownloadManager` to download files from my local server.

And the files get downloaded to :

```
file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.mobule.lms/files/Download/myFileName
```

But I need it within my application :

```
content://com.mypackage.myfiles/
```

Comment: You cannot download files using the `DownloadManager` to the data directory of your application. If you want that you'll have to use a HTTP client and download and save it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Can you please suggest any sample code or reference url.